# BottomNavigationBar закрывает View-элементы

Tags: android, android-xml

Я сделал активность, в которой имеется `FrameLayout` и `BottomNavigationBar`. Проблема в том, что `BottomNavigationBar` закрывает нижнюю часть `FrameLayout`. Что делать? Код разметки прилагаю ниже:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/placeholder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</FrameLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: указывать маржины равные 0dp - напрасная трата ресурсов устройства

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы используете `ConstraintLayout`, то для вашего `FrameLayout` для параметра `android:layout_height` укажите значение **0dp** вручную или в режиме **Design** редактирования макета для `layout_height` выберите `match_constraint`.

Так же для `FrameLayout` добавьте следующие атрибуты:

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/navigation"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```

Благодаря этому ваш `FrameLayout` заполнит всё оставшееся после `BottomNavigationView` пространство

Comment: Да, это помогло. Но теперь `TitleBar` наползает на элементы экрана.

Comment: @mixer-09, дополнил ответ атрибутами для `FrameLayout`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте изменить параметр `android: layout_heigh` на `0dp` и добавьте `android: layout_weight="1"` для `ImageView`. Взято [отсюда](http://askdev.info/questions/498767/bottom-navigation-bar-hides-part-of-a-view).

Comment: layout_weight - атрибут контейнера LinearLayout (а не ConstraintLayout или FrameLayout)